# Как называется подобный подход к обработке данных? Есть ли такой паттерн?

Tags: php, yii2, шаблоны-проектирования, поиск-библиотек

К примеру есть почтовый ящик с которого собираются письма, обрабатываются вложения и раскладываются в базе по таблицам.
Для отслеживания что обработано и с каким результатом к примеру в проекте есть такая таблица

```
 CREATE TABLE `processed_email` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mailid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `provider_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `try` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `date_receipt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `is_bad` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `is_done` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `mailid` (`mailid`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=135 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Данная сущность обрабатывается кастомным кодом, который был придуман на коленке.

Вопрос, как называется такой подход?
Есть ли такие паттерны?
Есть ли готовые решения на гитхабе под данную задачу с удобным функционалом?

Comment: У вас сервер вызывает фильтр при поступлении очередного письма или клиент (скажем, по imap) переодически  сканирует почтовый ящик?

Comment: @avp сервер по imap протоколу, по крону читает письма.

Comment: Наверное, (по названию?) тут подходит паттерн observer (наблюдатель).

Comment: @avp и каким боком тут паттерн наблюдатель? я так думаю вы не правильно поняли вопрос, я про технику отметки того что письмо обработано или не обработано а не про сам процесс обработки писем.

Comment: я про таблицу processed_email в которую пишется информация о выполненной работе над письмами

Comment: А как ваш вопрос надо было понимать? Как называется заполнение таблицы данными из  письма?

Comment: Посмотрите на таблицу... речь про систему помечающую отработанные вещи, речь про абстракцию, а не про конкретную ситуацию. Это может быть парсинг чего угодно, обработка чего угодно...

Comment: Из какого письма... Речь про дату когда была попытка обработать порцию данных, про количество попыток, про отметку о том что порцию данных удалось обработать или не обработать...